# Real time calculation of form with minimum order

Tags: javascript, php, html, calculation

I've borrowed some code from two different sources and splice them together. One works (The ordering total) but the 2nd one (Minimum order) does not. I'm a newb when it comes to Java and probably am just missing a command or something.

'total' is being used for both and should be re enabling the submit button once 'total' is above 20.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>temp</title>

<script language="javascript">
function calculate(form)
{
var item1 = form.item1.value;
var item2 = form.item2.value;
form.total.value = (item1 * 10) + (item2 * 30);
};
</script>

<script language="javascript">
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#total').val() >= 20)
        $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}, 1);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" >
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="757">
<tr>
<td width="224" align="center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
<td width="39" align="center"><strong>price</strong></td>
<td width="476" align="center"><strong>total</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="224">item1<input type="number" name="item1" size="20" onchange="calculate(this.form)" value="0"></td>
<td width="39">$10</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td width="224">item2<input type="number" name="item2" size="20" onchange="calculate(this.form)" value="0"> </td>
<td width="39">$30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="224"> </td>
<td width="39">total</td>
<td width="476"> <input type="number" name="total" size="20"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" disabled title="Order is below $20 minimum."></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ($('#total').val() >= 20 ?>)` should be `if ($('#total').val() >= 20)`

Comment: Looks like I left a end tag from some php I had tried to use earlier but that still doesn't solve the issue. It's still not enabling the submit button.

Comment: I've now corrected the ?> issue in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#total')` looks for element with id `total`, but you don't have it (you have only name),

so, by adding id - form is working

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>temp</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function calculate(form)
{
var item1 = form.item1.value;
var item2 = form.item2.value;
form.total.value = (item1 * 10) + (item2 * 30);
};
</script>

<script language="javascript">
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#total').val() >= 20)
        $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}, 1);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" >
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>price</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>total</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>item1<input type="number" name="item1" size="20" onchange="calculate(this.form)" value="0"></td>
<td width="39">$10</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>item2<input type="number" name="item2" size="20" onchange="calculate(this.form)" value="0"> </td>
<td>$30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td>total</td>
<td> <input type="number" id="total" name="total" size="20"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" disabled title="Order is below $20 minimum."></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes sense about the ID. Thankyou!  The other thing I seemed to have been missing was the jquery link. The fiddle I got the submit enable/disable code from didn't have it in their example even though it worked.